# Not able to move through all level of nodes from a xml source in my ssrs report

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am using xml data source for my ssrs report which is located on localhost/*.xml, the problem i am facing is to moving through all the level of nodes. I am using first time xml source... please guide me

Lets consider my xml source file looks somewhat similar to below code (Target-->Module-->NameSpace-->Type)

```
<CodeMetricsReport Version="10.0">
 <Targets>
 <Target Name="C:\CodeMetrix\CFT.ActiveReports.dll">
 <Modules>
 <Module Name="CFT.ActiveReports.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0" FileVersion="1.0.0.0">
 <Metrics>
 <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="60" />
 <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1,087" />
 <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="130" />
 <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="4" />
        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="11,350" />
      </Metrics>
      <Namespaces>
        <Namespace Name="CFT.ActiveReports">
          <Metrics>
            <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="44" />
            <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="955" />
            <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="84" />
            <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="4" />
            <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="10,882" />
          </Metrics>
          <Types>
            <Type Name="ReportHelper">
              <Metrics>
                <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="57" />
                <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="58" />
                <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="18" />
                <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1" />
                <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="158" />
              </Metrics>
```

......

In my dataset i can able to see fields -Version, Target_Name,Module_Name,AssemblyVersion, Fileversion,Name, Value and Metric. But I can't able to get the fields NameSpace and Type.

Currently in my query designer I am using the syntax

```
 <Query>
 <Elementpath>
 CodeMetricsReport.Version/Targets{}/Target.Name{}/Modules{}/Module.Name{}
 /Namespaces{}/Namespace.Name{}/Types{}/Type.Name{}/Metrics{Metric.Name,Value}
 </Elementpath>
 </Query>
```

Even if i am using the below syntax, I am getting the same result...

```
            <Query>
           <Elementpath>
           </Elementpath>
           </Query>
```

Please correct me if i am wrong,

Thank You

Comment: Let me brief it... for each target name there will be module as you can see it is a dll file names, and it's a 1-1 relationship. but for each module there will be more then 1 namespace and same for type. I want to make a bar report for modules where it will display the maintainability index etc. on click of each module it will move to its sub report and display maintainability index for all name space and one for drill through to type. but my dataset is not providing the information for namespace and type.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only problem, but I notice that your query says

```
/Namespaces{}/Namespaces.Name{}
```

...whereas the example XML suggests it should be

```
/Namespaces{}/Namespace.Name{}
```

Comment: Ann, It was just a typo mistake here not in my original query. My question is there a different format in xml to reach through all the nodes.